# .htaccess rewrite rule to ignore a directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am running a [Symphony](http://www.getsymphony.com/) installation out of the directory `symphony` but I want to remove that word from the URL in specific cases.

When a user visits

```
http://domain.com/demo
```

It should go to

```
http://domain.com/symphony/demo
```

because I've added a specific rule for `demo`. If I haven't added a specific rule for `demo` in the `.htaccess`, then it should resolve to

```
http://domain.com/demo
```

as typed. This will route it to another part of our app.

Comment: So you just want to redirect for specifically defined URLs?

Comment: Well, it should support `http://domain.com/demo/434324` going to `http://domain.com/symphony/demo/434324` without having to be added to the htaccess

Comment: Right, but just for stuff under `/demo` and other specific paths?

Comment: well, we would have other prefixes as well, like `live`, `public` etc.

Comment: think of `demo` as `foo`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^demo($|/.*$) symphony/demo$1
RewriteRule ^live($|/.*$) symphony/live$1
RewriteRule ^foo($|/.*$) symphony/foo$1
```

Note that not all PHP applications will handle this gracefully, as some look at the pre-rewrite URL to determine what content to serve.  Give it a try, we'll see if it works!

Comment: thx much .. will try soon

Comment: What is the `RewriteCond` for this?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck There aren't `RewriteCond` directives in this configuration, they aren't needed.

Comment: What is the entire rule? Rewrite needs to be turned on, right?

Comment: @KirkStrobeck Insert those lines directly before your line that says `DO NOT APPLY RULES WHEN REQUESTING "favicon.ico"`, enabling the engine is already done above that.

Comment: Oh, i see the confusion. I'm not using the above `.htaccess` as this (it turns out) will need to go in the directory above.